# Node and taxonomy term have same URL?

Tags: path-aliases

By adjusting URL alias patterns I've made nodes types and taxonomy terms have overlapping URLs. The nodes have a 1 to 1 relationship with terms. At the URL I want to show the node and not the normal term page.

This seems to be working perfectly for what I need, but are there any risks or edge cases I'm not aware of? When a node and a term have the same URL does the node always win out?